# Navigating to another screen gets slower and slower each time i repeat click, go back, click, go back

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `Navigator.push` and `MaterialPageRoute()` to navigate to another screen. But navigation to other screens gets slower and slower becuase in my `initState()` i have a method which initializes the json data which i show each time i navigate to another screen. The json data is big and i only use one file with big json data which has objects and each object is shown i different screens. In my usecase i have to use one file with big json data.

In my `initState()` i initialize the data i grabbed with the method `setTestData()` and inside this method i set the data inside an object:

```
  late Map<String, dynamic> grabbedData = {};

  setTestData() async {
    await TestData()
        .getTestData()
        .then((result) => setState(() => grabbedData = result));
  }

  @override
  initState() {
    setTestData();
    super.initState();
  }
```

In my view i can for example navigate to another screen and then show different objects inside the same object json i grabbed in `setTestData()`. I only use one view called `AppView()` to show different screen so when i navigate for example from screen A to B, both A and B screen are shown with AppView() widget. This is necessary for my use case which is irrelevant for this question.

This is the navigation which i use to load another screen and which technacly runs `initState()` from `AppView()` again because the previous route is also `AppView()`:

```
 Navigator.push(
                                                context,
                                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                                    maintainState: false,
                                                    builder: (_) => AppView(
                                                          selectedMenuItems:
                                                              grabbedData['data']
                                                                      ['views'][
                                                                  widget.selectedMenuItems[
                                                                          index]
                                                                      [
                                                                      'content']],
                                                        )));
```

But the problem is that each time i navigate to `AppView()` and click back on my phone to show previous data from `AppView()` and navigate again, it re-initializes the state and so the proces is slowed after i repeat it a couple of times. How do i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Better to use **[Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider)** package for this task. Provider does not rebuild the widget rather it only updates the state of the widget so it is faster. Then, you can get your data or data stream only once at the beginning of your app or a particular screen. No need to generate data each time. Also, provider automatically disposes data when the screen is closed. It is recommended by flutter team as well and an awesome package. For more example, check some YouTube videos. For your particular problem, I think it is better to use **provider.value**. Check the references and hopefully later on you will understand what is a **provider.value** object.

If you are generating new data every time then you need to set your `provider.value` each time where you are using `Navigator.push`, otherwise if you do not use your provider at the beginning of your app at `MaterialApp` section then after the push the provider won't be available.

As an example, to add provider inside a push please follow the following code snippet:

```
Navigator.push(context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: ((context) {
    
    return StreamProvider<User>.value(
        initialData: initialUserData,
        value: userDataStream,
        child: const UpdateUser(),
    );
})));
```

Next, access the value in the UpdateUser page like this:

```
final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
```

If you are not using any data stream then just try the normal **ChangeNotifierProvider** and get the value from the **Consumer**. Try some youtube tutorials and you will love it.

Comment: I don't understand how you can implement `provider.value` inside `Navigator.push`

Comment: Should i use `Provider` in the `main.dart` file, because  the `MaterialApp` is inside this file. I use `Scaffold` for `AppView` widget

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please check the sample. For more information, please read the provider package documentation or check some tutorial on youtube.

Comment: I don't understand what you do with `UpdateUser()` and `User` model

Comment: I don't know how i can implement `Provider` for my use case

Comment: That's just an example. You should try learning Provider class. Follow some tutorials and learn it. Then, you will understand.

Comment: Do i have to use a model like in the example`<User>` because i don't use model

Comment: and what should i put inside initialData and value if i don't use `Stream`?